# How to automatically open the Plot Zoom window and save the plot from the window in R

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I am trying to automate the process of plotting and saving Manhattan plots. However, of all the processes that I have tried so far, the quality and detail of the automated plots are significantly lower than the manual method, where I first plot the Manhattan plot, then zoom the plot into a Plot Zoom window, and then saving the plot there. In the Plot Zoom version, the plot displays much more details than the automated version. You can see each individual data point more clearly. Is there a way for me automatically plot and save the Plot Zoom version of the Manhattan Plot?

The general methods I've tried resolves something around this:

```
#data_file is just a list of the various files names
plot_list = list()
for (i in 1:length(data_files)) {
  df <- GSL_data[[i]]
  manhattan(df, chr = ">CHR", bp = "Positions", p = "P-Value", snp = "SNP-Hash",
            main = paste("Manhattan Plot - ", data_files[i]))
  p = recordPlot()
  plot_list[[i]] = p
  file_name = paste(data_files[i], ".png", sep = "")
  png(file_name, width = 2218, height = 1464, res = 300)
  print(plot_list[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: you need to give more information. What format are you saving as? what are 'all the processes you have tried so far'? how are you making the plots? can you include any code/extra information?

Comment: I just added an example of what I used to automate the Manhattan Plot. I hope that it can help with answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying [ggsave](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html). All you need to do is adjust the dimensions you want.

In your code replace

```r
png(file_name, width = 2218, height = 1464, res = 300)
print(plot_list[[i]])
dev.off()
```

with

```
ggsave(filename = file_name, plot = p, width = 4, height = 4)
```

Comment: Yes, that was also one of the methods that I have tried since I thought it would return me with what I want. However, the result returned me with exactly the same thing as the code in the example. It seems that adjusting resolution and dimensions does not increase the details of the graph itself...